# Is a revocation certificate still valid after updating GPG key's expiration?

Tags: gnupg, certificate-revocation

When I first generated my GPG key I created a revocation certificate for it as well. Now I've edited my key and its subkeys and updated their expiration. Do I need to generate a new revocation certificate?